# Problem with Network 19.10 last version! Please help me!

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, 19.10

**i can connect to the internet with my phone (phone hotspot), but i can't connect to the home internet.
when i try to connect to home internet, it just spins ...
(internet wlan logo with three dots)
and (it works normally with the cable)**